# Getting Data into the JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to visulize Coordinates on the map . Data is Coming form json.

I am getting and error Push is undefined. I am passing the Array  but getting error

Here is the Code

```
 var testCtrl = this;
 testCtrl.allOrgUnits = response.organisationUnits;
 console.log(testCtrl.allOrgUnits)

 for (i = 0; i < testCtrl.allOrgUnits.length; i++) {
   if(testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates != undefined && testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates.length < 200) {
     testCtrl.geoCoords.push(new Array(testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].name, testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates.substring(1,testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates.length-1).split(",")));
    }
  }

 // Add the coordinates to the map.
 addMarkers(testCtrl.geoCoords);
});
```

JSON Data is like

`organization units [{ "name":david  , "coordinates""[ 10.24 ,23.80]  { "name":phil  , "coordinates""[ 35.80 ,23.80]`

Here is the Function addMarkers

```
function addMarkers(coordinates) {
    var marker;
    markers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) { 
        // Create and add a new marker per coordinate.
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1][1], coordinates[i][1][0]),
            map: map,
            title: coordinates[i][0],
            icon: blueMarker,
            current: false,
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        // Add a listener to each marker, so that they will display the name of the facility when clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent("<div class='info'><h4>" + coordinates[i][0] + "</h4>Facility</div>");
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
```

Comment: What is `this` in `var testCtrl = this;`? `testCtrl.geoCoords` is probably not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to initialize `geoCords` to be an array before trying to push something.

```
testCtrl.geoCoords = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call push method on `undefined` 
You are doing this

testCtrl.geoCoords.push()

where testCtrl has no property geoCoords, so first initialize this property like

```
testCtrl.geoCoords = []
```

Now it is an empty array ,  you can use push method on this

Comment: Thanks .. Now not getting any error . but cannot see the map

Comment: can you create a fiddle or jsbin so we can see any errors

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your json into Object, it might be easier after that.

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
listPersonCoordinates = mapper.readValue(query_result, new TypeReference<ArrayList<PersonCoordinate>>(){})
for (PersonCoordinate pc : listPersonCoordinate) {
    pc.getName();
    pc.getCoordinate();
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

and

```
public Class PersonCoordinate {
    String name;
    ArrayList<double> coordinate;

    // getters + setters + constructor
}
```

Hope this help :)

Edit : Your JSON looks strangely formatted. misses some `"`