# Passing Json to google map api with formatting

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to Understand this peace of code. can anyone help me to understand this. sorry for the pretty basic question

```
testCtrl.geoCoords.push(new Array(testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].name, testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates.substring(1,testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates.length-1).split(",")));
```

I have coordinates like

```
coordinates":"[-12.2231,8.466]
```

How this peace of code is changing the coordinates.

```
coordinates.substring(1,testCtrl.allOrgUnits[i].coordinates.length-1).split(",")));
```

Comment: You could add this as comment under the solution answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973087/getting-data-into-the-json/33973153#33973153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if coordinates is a string like `"[-12.2231,8.466]"`

`coordinates.substring(1, coordinates.length - 1).split(",")` will return the Array `["-12,2231", "8.466"]`.

`coordinates.substring(1, coordinates.length - 1) == "-12.2231,8.466"`
then
`"-12.2231,8.466".split(",") == ["-12,2231", "8.466"]`.

You can find the method documentation here: [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)